# Failed to compile x264 library for android, error description: clang:error no such file or directory

Tags: android, shell, x264

I use a shell script to compile the x264 library to the android platform, the architecture is armeabi-v7a,The x264 library was cloned from github。

I am sure I have those directories,and I checked the search engine such as google,No one encountered the same situation

```
ANDROID_NDK=/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b
SYSROOT=$ANDROID_NDK/platforms/android-16/arch-arm
CROSS_PREFIX=$ANDROID_NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi- 
4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
EXTRA_CFLAGS="-march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon - 
D__ANDROID__ -D__ARM_ARCH_7__ -D__ARM_ARCH_7A__"
EXTRA_LDFLAGS="-nostdlib"
PREFIX=`pwd`/libs/armeabi-v7a

./configure --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --host=arm-linux \
    --sysroot=$SYSROOT \
    --cross-prefix=$CROSS_PREFIX \
    --extra-cflags="$EXTRA_CFLAGS" \
    --extra-ldflags="$EXTRA_LDFLAGS" \
    --enable-pic \
    --enable-static \
    --enable-strip \
    --disable-cli \
    --disable-asm
   # --disable-win32thread \
   # --disable-avs \
   # --disable-swscale \
   # --disable-lavf \
   # --disable-ffms \
   # --disable-gpac \
   # --disable-lsmash \
   # --disable-opencl

make clean
make STRIP= -j8 install || exit 1

cp -f $PREFIX/libx264.a $PREFIX
```

The error is here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywNaF.jpg)
The result is that this x264 library cannot be used. Can someone help me? thanks very much

Ok, I generated the config.log file during the compilation of x264, I hope it is an error log file, the log content is as follows:

```
checking for -Werror=unknown-warning-option... no
Failed commandline was:
--------------------------------------------------
/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc conftest.c  -Wall -I. -I$(SRCPATH) --sysroot=/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-16/arch-arm -march=armv5te -msoft-float -D__ANDROID__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TEJ__  -Werror=unknown-warning-option   --sysroot=/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-16/arch-arm -nostdlib -o conftest
cc1: error: -Werror=unknown-warning-option: no option -Wunknown-warning-option
--------------------------------------------------
Failed program was:
--------------------------------------------------
int main (void) {  return 0; }
--------------------------------------------------
x264 configure script
Command line options: "--prefix=/Users/Project/bishe/x264/libs/armeabi-v7a" "--host=arm-linux" "--sysroot=/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-16/arch-arm" "--cross-prefix=/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-" "--extra-cflags=-march=armv5te" "-msoft-float" "-D__ANDROID__" "-D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__" "-D__ARM_ARCH_5TEJ__" "--extra-ldflags=-nostdlib" "--enable-pic" "--enable-static" "--enable-strip" "--disable-cli" "--disable-asm" "--disable-win32thread" "--disable-avs" "--disable-swscale" "--disable-lavf" "--disable-ffms" "--disable-gpac" "--disable-lsmash" "--disable-opencl"

checking whether /Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc works... yes
checking whether /Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc supports for( int i = 0; i < 9; i++ ); with -std=gnu99... yes
checking for pthread_create(0,0,0,0); in pthread.h... no
Failed commandline was:
--------------------------------------------------
/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc conftest.c  -Wall -I. -I$(SRCPATH) --sysroot=/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-16/arch-arm -march=armv5te -msoft-float -D__ANDROID__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TEJ__ -std=gnu99 -D_GNU_SOURCE  -lpthread   --sysroot=/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-16/arch-arm -nostdlib -lm -o conftest
conftest.c:1:21: fatal error: pthread.h: No such file or directory
 #include <pthread.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
--------------------------------------------------
Failed program was:
--------------------------------------------------
#include <pthread.h>
int main (void) { pthread_create(0,0,0,0); return 0; }
--------------------------------------------------
checking for pthread_create(0,0,0,0); in pthread.h... no
Failed commandline was:
--------------------------------------------------
/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc conftest.c  -Wall -I. -I$(SRCPATH) --sysroot=/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-16/arch-arm -march=armv5te -msoft-float -D__ANDROID__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TEJ__ -std=gnu99 -D_GNU_SOURCE     --sysroot=/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-16/arch-arm -nostdlib -lm -o conftest
conftest.c:1:21: fatal error: pthread.h: No such file or directory
 #include <pthread.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
--------------------------------------------------
Failed program was:
--------------------------------------------------
#include <pthread.h>
int main (void) { pthread_create(0,0,0,0); return 0; }
--------------------------------------------------
checking for log2f(2); in math.h... no
Failed commandline was:
--------------------------------------------------
/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc conftest.c  -Wall -I. -I$(SRCPATH) --sysroot=/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-16/arch-arm -march=armv5te -msoft-float -D__ANDROID__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TEJ__ -std=gnu99 -D_GNU_SOURCE     --sysroot=/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-16/arch-arm -nostdlib -lm -o conftest
conftest.c:1:18: fatal error: math.h: No such file or directory
 #include <math.h>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
--------------------------------------------------
Failed program was:
--------------------------------------------------
#include <math.h>
int main (void) { log2f(2); return 0; }
--------------------------------------------------
checking for strtok_r(0, 0, 0); in string.h... no
Failed commandline was:
--------------------------------------------------
/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc conftest.c  -Wall -I. -I$(SRCPATH) --sysroot=/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-16/arch-arm -march=armv5te -msoft-float -D__ANDROID__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TEJ__ -std=gnu99 -D_GNU_SOURCE     --sysroot=/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-16/arch-arm -nostdlib -lm -o conftest
conftest.c:1:20: fatal error: string.h: No such file or directory
 #include <string.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
--------------------------------------------------
Failed program was:
--------------------------------------------------
#include <string.h>
int main (void) { strtok_r(0, 0, 0); return 0; }
--------------------------------------------------
checking for clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, 0); in time.h... no
Failed commandline was:
--------------------------------------------------
/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc conftest.c  -Wall -I. -I$(SRCPATH) --sysroot=/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-16/arch-arm -march=armv5te -msoft-float -D__ANDROID__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TEJ__ -std=gnu99 -D_GNU_SOURCE     --sysroot=/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-16/arch-arm -nostdlib -lm -o conftest
conftest.c:1:18: fatal error: time.h: No such file or directory
 #include <time.h>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
--------------------------------------------------
Failed program was:
--------------------------------------------------
#include <time.h>
int main (void) { clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, 0); return 0; }
--------------------------------------------------
checking for clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, 0); in time.h... no
Failed commandline was:
--------------------------------------------------
/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc conftest.c  -Wall -I. -I$(SRCPATH) --sysroot=/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-16/arch-arm -march=armv5te -msoft-float -D__ANDROID__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TEJ__ -std=gnu99 -D_GNU_SOURCE  -lrt   --sysroot=/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-16/arch-arm -nostdlib -lm -o conftest
conftest.c:1:18: fatal error: time.h: No such file or directory
 #include <time.h>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
--------------------------------------------------
Failed program was:
--------------------------------------------------
#include <time.h>
int main (void) { clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, 0); return 0; }
--------------------------------------------------
checking whether defined(MAP_PRIVATE) is true... no
--------------------------------------------------
conftest.c:1:22: fatal error: sys/mman.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sys/mman.h>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
--------------------------------------------------
Failed program was:
--------------------------------------------------
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#if !(defined(MAP_PRIVATE)) 
#error  
#endif 
--------------------------------------------------
checking for uint32_t test_vec __attribute__ ((vector_size (16))) = {0,1,2,3}; in stdint.h... no
Failed commandline was:
--------------------------------------------------
/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc conftest.c  -Wall -I. -I$(SRCPATH) --sysroot=/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-16/arch-arm -march=armv5te -msoft-float -D__ANDROID__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TEJ__ -std=gnu99 -D_GNU_SOURCE     --sysroot=/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-16/arch-arm -nostdlib -lm -o conftest
In file included from conftest.c:1:0:
/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/include/stdint.h:9:26: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
 # include_next <stdint.h>
                          ^
compilation terminated.
--------------------------------------------------
Failed program was:
--------------------------------------------------
#include <stdint.h>
int main (void) { uint32_t test_vec __attribute__ ((vector_size (16))) = {0,1,2,3}; return 0; }
--------------------------------------------------
checking for stdio.h... no
Failed commandline was:
--------------------------------------------------
/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc conftest.c  -Wall -I. -I$(SRCPATH) --sysroot=/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-16/arch-arm -march=armv5te -msoft-float -D__ANDROID__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TEJ__ -std=gnu99 -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC  -shared -Wl,-Bsymbolic   --sysroot=/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-16/arch-arm -nostdlib -lm -o conftest
conftest.c:1:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdio.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
--------------------------------------------------
Failed program was:
--------------------------------------------------
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {  return 0; }
--------------------------------------------------
checking for -fno-tree-vectorize... yes
checking for fseeko(stdin,0,0); in stdio.h... no
Failed commandline was:
--------------------------------------------------
/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc conftest.c -O3 -ffast-math  -Wall -I. -I$(SRCPATH) --sysroot=/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-16/arch-arm -march=armv5te -msoft-float -D__ANDROID__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TEJ__ -std=gnu99 -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-tree-vectorize     --sysroot=/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-16/arch-arm -nostdlib -lm -s -o conftest
conftest.c:1:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdio.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
--------------------------------------------------
Failed program was:
--------------------------------------------------
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) { fseeko(stdin,0,0); return 0; }
--------------------------------------------------
checking for fseeko64(stdin,0,0); in stdio.h... no
Failed commandline was:
--------------------------------------------------
/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc conftest.c -O3 -ffast-math  -Wall -I. -I$(SRCPATH) --sysroot=/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-16/arch-arm -march=armv5te -msoft-float -D__ANDROID__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TEJ__ -std=gnu99 -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-tree-vectorize     --sysroot=/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-16/arch-arm -nostdlib -lm -s -o conftest
conftest.c:1:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdio.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
--------------------------------------------------
Failed program was:
--------------------------------------------------
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) { fseeko64(stdin,0,0); return 0; }
--------------------------------------------------
checking for _fseeki64(stdin,0,0); in stdio.h... no
Failed commandline was:
--------------------------------------------------
/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc conftest.c -O3 -ffast-math  -Wall -I. -I$(SRCPATH) --sysroot=/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-16/arch-arm -march=armv5te -msoft-float -D__ANDROID__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TEJ__ -std=gnu99 -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-tree-vectorize     --sysroot=/Users/Project/devtools/android-sdk-macosx/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-16/arch-arm -nostdlib -lm -s -o conftest
conftest.c:1:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdio.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
--------------------------------------------------
Failed program was:
--------------------------------------------------
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) { _fseeki64(stdin,0,0); return 0; }
--------------------------------------------------
checking for -Wshadow... yes
checking for -Wmaybe-uninitialized... yes

platform:      ARM
byte order:    little-endian
system:        LINUX
cli:           no
libx264:       internal
shared:        no
static:        yes
asm:           no
interlaced:    yes
avs:           no
lavf:          no
ffms:          no
mp4:           no
gpl:           yes
thread:        no
opencl:        no
filters:       crop select_every
lto:           no
debug:         no
gprof:         no
strip:         yes
PIC:           yes
bit depth:     all
chroma format: all
```

Comment: Please don’t post pictures of errors. Post the error text. Thank you.

Comment: Now that I have shown all the error log files,so can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Check the path you mentioned as your directory

Comment: Yes, I checked those files, but I think it might not be those errors. I can see from the generated config.log that they are not the errors displayed by the terminal.